# Undo List changes from DataGridView

Tags: c#, list, datagridview

I want to reset a List to how it was before being edited in a DataGridView upon clicking an exit button.

From what I understand, a List is a reference class, so any change to my DataGridView is automatically changed in my List as well. My thinking is to create an un-editable copy or a hard copy of the List and set the original list equal to it when closing. When attempting to use AsReadOnly for my solution, printing my list reveals to me that editing the values in the DataGridView change it as well.

My Code:

```
dgvPreview.DataSource = typeof(Parameter);
dgvPreview.DataSource = frmMain._paramList;
...
public static List<Parameter> originalList = new List<Parameter>(frmMain._paramList);
IList<Parameter> readOnly = originalList.AsReadOnly();
...
frmMain._paramList = readOnly;
```

Can I make a backup list for this purpose and can I use AsReadOnly for it?

Comment: No, AsReadOnly makes the _list_ readonly, not the items in it. To use a backup list, you will have to make "deep copies" of the items and store the new instances in a separate list.

Comment: That's why this is usually done with databinding to a DataTable, or something else that tracks changes to items.